# Limpar campos com Jquery

Tags: jquery

Colegas. Estou tentando limpar os campos após o submit de um formulário, porém não estou conseguindo. Vejam:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#resposta").ajaxStart(function(){ 
    $(this).html("Mensagem sendo enviada, por favor aguarde..."); 
           }        
        );
$("#submit").click(function() {
var nome     = $("#nome").val();
var email    = $("#email").val();
var assunto    = $("#assunto").val();
var mensagem = $("#mensagem").val();
$.post('enviar.php', { nome: nome, email: email, assunto: assunto, mensagem: mensagem, contato: true }, function(data) {

if (data !== false) {
$("#resposta").html(data);
}else{
$("#nome").val("");
$("#email").val("");
$("#assunto").val("");
$("#mensagem").val("");

    }

});
return false;
});
});
```

Tentei das seguintes formas e também não funcionou:

```
$("#form")[0].reset();
```

e

```
$("#form").trigger("reset");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A grosso modo usando o [submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) do formulário no `Jquery` ficaria:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#myForm").submit(function() { //no submit do formulário
    $('#myForm input').val(""); //coloca todos valores de todos inputs do form como vazio
    $('#myForm input[type = submit]').val("Enviar"); //recoloca o texto no botão
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Campo 01" name="campo01"/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Campo 02" name="campo02"/>
  
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" /> 
</form>

<input type="text" placeholder="Campo Fora" name="campofora"/>
```

Seu código ficaria assim para limpar o formulário só se tivesse sucesso no `submit`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#resposta").ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).html("Mensagem sendo enviada, por favor aguarde...");
    });
    $("#form").submit(function() {
        var nome = $("#nome").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var assunto = $("#assunto").val();
        var mensagem = $("#mensagem").val();
        $.post('enviar.php', {
            nome: nome,
            email: email,
            assunto: assunto,
            mensagem: mensagem,
            contato: true
        }, function(data) {

            if (data !== false) {
                $("#resposta").html(data);
                $("#form input").val(""); //limpa todos inputs do formulário
                $("#form input[type = submit]").val("Enviar"); //redefine botão submit
            } else {
                $("#nome").val("");
                $("#email").val("");
                $("#assunto").val("");
                $("#mensagem").val("");

            }

        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Olá lvcs. Perdoe-me a pergunta, pois sou leigo em Jquery. Onde incluo o seu código exatamente? Obrigado!

Comment: Está bem, vou fazer usando o seu código.

Comment: prontinho, deve funcionar.

Comment: Perfeito lvcs...funcionou... obrigado pela força. Abraço

Comment: @ivcs, so uma dica, quando for limpar os campos utilize um seletor dentro do escopo do form, senao voce vai acabar limpando todos os inputs da tela, outra coisa, voce pode especificar os types que serao limpos nao havendo a necessidade de preencher o nome do campo submit.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues sobre o escopo, eu havia feito isso, após a primeira edição da resposta (pois lembrei disso).. Sobre os type, é bem mais simples redefinir do que ficar selecionando por tipo, pois podemos ter diversos tipos no mesmo formulário.